# Creating an OpenGL texture with alpha using NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: opengl, transparency, alpha, nsbitmapimagerep, glblendfunc

I am loading a PNG using:

```
theImage = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

from which I can successfully create a gl texture and render correctly without any transparency. However, when I switch blending on using:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

The texture renders with the correct transparent background, but the image colours are incorrect.

I have tried several options in the blend function, `GL_SRC_ALPHA`, `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`, `GL_ONE`, `GL_DST_ALPHA`, etc.

I was taught maybe I need to reorder the bits in the image data, maybe the channels have been mixed up, but I would not expect it to render correctly when blending is off in that case.

Alternatively, I could use libPNG I guess, but I would like to try using a `NSBitmapImageRep` if it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

How about supplying a screenshot?

---

Anyway, your blending function is wrong either way for simple transparency channel blending. It should be either

- normal alpha: `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

or

- premultiplied alpha: `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

Comment: Nail, head, hit,,, 
 
My blend func is wrong, but this fixed it.  

Thanks